# How do I clear all of the Event Logs in Windows?

Tags: c#, logging, windows-services

How do I clear all of the Event Logs in Windows using C#?

Comment: So what is your question now? If you want a windows service, just read how to make it and do the needed things.

Comment: No thats not it am trying to delete all event logs in windows

Comment: With powershell: http://kristofmattei.be/2011/06/14/clear-all-event-logs-on-windows-using-powershell/ (one of the first results when searching).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
using System.Diagnostics;

using(var eventLog = new EventLog("Security", System.Environment.MachineName);
    eventLog.Clear();
```

to delete the security events logs.

to delete all:

```
foreach (var eventLog in EventLog.GetEventLogs())
{         
     eventLog.Clear();
     eventLog.Dispose();
}
```